# Yii2 - form and related gridview on the same page

Tags: php, yii2

Can somebody give me a direction as to how I can render the gridview the form page itself in YIi2

I am really new to Yii and wondering how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use yii\grid\GridView;

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput() ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $itemDataProvider,
    'columns' => [

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'start_date',
        'end_date',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn-success']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Pagination equals to 20 by default. [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html) You can read docs about yii\data\Pagination and change default pagination value. [Here](http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2014/04/16/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview-yii2/) You can see good tutorial about filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add put Gridview in modal with Pjax  outside form tag so if you want filter will not be submitted a main form
for example

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

//button for showing modal
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_large">Browse</button>

 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<div class="modal" id="modal_large" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModalHead" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="largeModalHead">Large Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                Pjax::begin([
                    'enablePushState' => false
                ]);
                echo GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $imageDataProvider,
                    'filterModel' => $imageSearchModel,
                    'columns' => [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                        'field',
                        'created_at:datetime',
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                    ],
                ]);
                Pjax::end();
                ?>     </div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rendering the form and gridview on single page view.

### Controller Code

Include the parameters you want to render:

- `$model` for the ***_form*** view.
- `$searchModel` and `$dataProvider` for the ***index*** view.

  ```
      public function actionCreate()
      {
          $model = new WorkflowStep;

          if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
          {
              return $this->redirect([
                  'view', 'step_id' => $model->step_id
              ]);
          }

          $searchModel = new WorkflowStepSearch();
          $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

          return $this->render('create', [
              'model' => $model,
              'searchModel' => $searchModel,
              'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          ]);
      }
  ```

### View Code

Now in the app/views/create.php all we need to do is render the additional desired views and pass the intended parameters.

```
        <?php

        use yii\helpers\Html;

        /* @var $this yii\web\View */
        /* @var $model app\modules\tickets\models\WorkflowStep */

        $this->title = 'Create Workflow Step';
        $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Workflow Steps', 'url' => ['index']];
        $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

        ?>
        <div class="workflow-step-create">

            <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

            <?= $this->render('_form', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]) ?>

            <?= $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]) ?>

        </div>
```